# PHP Images rename double digits

Tags: php

I have pictures in a folder and I would like to rename them sequentially to a two digit number. I browsed and tried a lot of solutions but I didn't manage to find what I am looking for. I grown desperate now. I managed to find this code but it renames one digit from 1 to 9, and two digits from 10 onward. I would like it to numerate starting 01.jpg, 02.jpg, 03.jpg, etc...

```
<?php

$files = glob('../thumbs/*');

foreach($files as $i => $name) {
    $newname = sprintf('../thumbs/%d.jpg', $i+2);
    if ($newname != $name) {
        rename($name, $newname);
    }
}


?>
```

How can I modify the above code to make it a double digit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `sprintf('../thumbs/%d.jpg', $i+2);` to `sprintf('../thumbs/%02d.jpg', $i+2);`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify width of the integer number using a digit preceding the `d` in `%d`.

Instead of `sprintf('../thumbs/%d.jpg', $i+2);` use `sprintf('../thumbs/%02d.jpg', $i+2);`

[See sprintf docs also](http://php.net/sprintf)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest str_pad http://www.php.net/str_pad for a more flexible approach:

```
  $files = glob('../thumbs/*');

    foreach($files as $i => $name) {
  {
         $index = str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

        $newname = sprintf('../thumbs/%d.jpg', $index);
        if ($newname != $name) {
            rename($name, $newname);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$files = glob('../thumbs/*');

foreach($files as $i => $name) {
    if ($i < 10) {
        $index = "0".$i;
    }
    else {
        $index = $i;
    }
    $newname = sprintf('../thumbs/%d.jpg', $index);
    if ($newname != $name) {
        rename($name, $newname);
    }
}
```

?>